# SharePoint Designer 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, 2016

During the *Ignite 2015 Conference* it has been announced that there will be no SharePoint Designer 2016.

Will there be another tool provided?

How should I manage and maintain workflow, content type, list and so on - without SPD?

Comment: To be honest my clients used SPD a lot for XSLT customization and I think is a great tool. I did expect Microsoft to put back design view get some more new features that can help us as well the clients

Answer (score 3):

Since SharePoint Server 2016 is built on the same code base as SharePoint 2013 and the fact that you still can use SharePoint Designer 2013 on SharePoint Online, there are reasons to believe that SharePoint Designer 2013 will function very well with SharePoint Server 2016. There may be features that can’t be used, but you have other tools available such as Visual Studio, PowerShell, Browser and Design Manager.

Reference: [Ignite 2015 Announcement – There will be no SharePoint Designer 2016](http://ericoverfield.com/ignite-2015-announcement-there-will-be-no-sharepoint-designer-2016/)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use SharePoint Designer 2013 64x with SharePoint Server 2016.

Also, you should read [SharePoint Designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in SharePoint Server 2016, What’s the alternatives ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)